# To merge two sheet into one

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet in the following format:

```
Sheet A contains 

FilePath | Value1

E:\xampp\htdocs\D1.php | 1

E:\xampp\htdocs\D2.php | 1

Sheet B contains 

FilePath | Value2

E:\xampp\htdocs\D2.php | 2

Output sheet:

Sheet C must contains 

FilePath | Value1 | Value2

E:\xampp\htdocs\D1.php | 1 | #NA

E:\xampp\htdocs\D2.php | 1 | 2
```

To solve this I thought to add a new column in sheet A named "Value2" and then used **VLOOKUP(A1,'SheetB'!A:B,1,FALSE)** for row1, **VLOOKUP(A2,'SheetB'!A:B,1,FALSE)** for row2 and so on, but the output "#N/A" for all rows despite the fact that SheetB contains data for D2.php.

How can I resolve this? Is this is happening because cell values are "Absolute path"? Is there any other method?

Please help!

Comment: typo: third parameter should be 2, not 1. Although error was that sheet B filepath contained some invisible symbol that I discovered after opening the file in ms excel 2007...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #N/A error means that the lookup value cannot be found. Double check that the values are indeed a perfect match. There may be trailing spaces, for example.

Also, if you want to return the value, then the third parameter should be 2, not 1, since you want the value in the second column of the lookup range.